# How to open a mailbox when launching (neo)mutt?

Tags: mutt

From time to time I want `neomutt` to open a different mailbox when launching it. I tried something like `neomutt -e "change-folder ${FOLDER_NAME}`, but it says that `change-folder` is not a command.

Comment: `mutt -f folder_file_name` works if you know the file name for the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutt has a `-f` option that you can use to select a mailbox on the command line.  The option takes the path to the mailbox as its argument. This works with both `mutt` and `neomutt`, e.g.

```
mutt -f Mail/inbox-work
```

I believe that it also supports opening IMAP mailboxes if you give it an IMAP URI.

Comment: Opening IMAP URIs do indeed work, e.g.: `mutt -f "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/[Gmail]/All Mail"`

Comment: Works also virtual-mailboxes (in neomutt with named-mailboxes too) if full path to notmuch database is provided e.g.: `neomutt -f "notmuch:///PATH_TO_NM?query=tag:inbox"` PATH_TO_NM is the same as config variable `nm_default_uri`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change-folder as a command, then you must

```
push "<change-folder>FOLDER\n"
```

- The use of double-quotes allow $ expansion and spaces inside FOLDER.
- The \n at the end is a needed carriage return because the function is interactive or the user will be consulted.

Note: push syntax is like macro syntax, but has no key or description.